# Proxmox web interface is not accessible

Tags: panel, proxmox

I have a PC with Proxmox. I have been using it half year ago. It was 5.4 version. I've started it yesterday, but couldn't connect to it using webinterface: `192.168.1.21:8006`. Chrome said: `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`
Looking for solution, I've found it could be solved by

1) Upgrade. I upgraded from 5.4 to 6.1 and it did not resolved the issue 
2) Reset certificates: `pvecm updatecerts -f`. It did not resolved the issue.
3) Clear browser's cookies. There were no cookies. I've also used Chrome's incognito mode and different browsers that never been connected to my Proxmox server.

```
root@proxmox:~# netstat -na | grep 8006
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8006            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

root@proxmox:~# pveversion
pve-manager/6.1-7/13e58d5e (running kernel: 5.3.13-3-pve)

root@proxmox:~# systemctl status pveproxy
● pveproxy.service - PVE API Proxy Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/pveproxy.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-02-07 23:18:10 EET; 34min ago
  Process: 1009 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/pvecm updatecerts --silent (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1011 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pveproxy start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1013 (pveproxy)
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 127.7M
   CGroup: /system.slice/pveproxy.service
           ├─1013 pveproxy
           ├─1014 pveproxy worker
           ├─1015 pveproxy worker
           └─1016 pveproxy worker

Feb 07 23:18:08 proxmox systemd[1]: Starting PVE API Proxy Server...
Feb 07 23:18:10 proxmox pveproxy[1013]: starting server
Feb 07 23:18:10 proxmox pveproxy[1013]: starting 3 worker(s)
Feb 07 23:18:10 proxmox pveproxy[1013]: worker 1014 started
Feb 07 23:18:10 proxmox pveproxy[1013]: worker 1015 started
Feb 07 23:18:10 proxmox pveproxy[1013]: worker 1016 started
Feb 07 23:18:10 proxmox systemd[1]: Started PVE API Proxy Server.
```

I could connect to it using `telnet 192.168.1.21 8006`. Log displayed no errors. Runing by `pveproxy -debug=1 start` displayed nothing special in case of browser's page refreshing:

```
root@proxmox:~# pveproxy start -debug=1
9190: ACCEPT FH10 CONN1
9191: ACCEPT FH10 CONN1
close connection AnyEvent::Handle=HASH(0x560ee2f16cf0)
9190: CLOSE FH10 CONN0
close connection AnyEvent::Handle=HASH(0x560ee2f16cf0)
9191: CLOSE FH10 CONN0
9191: ACCEPT FH10 CONN1
close connection AnyEvent::Handle=HASH(0x560ee2f13ac0)
9191: CLOSE FH10 CONN0
9190: ACCEPT FH10 CONN1
close connection AnyEvent::Handle=HASH(0x560ee38bff60)
9190: CLOSE FH10 CONN0
9189: ACCEPT FH10 CONN1
close connection AnyEvent::Handle=HASH(0x560ee2f16cf0)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By creating the question, I was reviewing advice that did not work. I wanted to include them into the question to show what I've tried and what did not help. 
Looking for that I've found an advice to check protocol. So I've discovered the cause of the issue.

I haven't used Proxmox very long time, so I forgot it should be accessible only through `https://192.168.1.21:8006`, not just by `192.168.1.21:8006`. But after accessing it through `https`, Chrome remembered it and used https even if I typed `http://...`

Answer (score 0):

I had two interfaces, `vmbr0` - WAN (192.168.x.x) and `vmbr1` - LAN (10.26.x.x). Although internet access was working, I could not access the proxmox's web UI from the LAN, only the WAN.

After much searching and fiddling around I discovered proxmox binds the UI to the bridge with the static IP and gateway address. I'd set this on my WAN `vmbr0` (and is the default behaviour during setup).

Once I moved my static IP and gateway to `vmbr1` in `/etc/network/interfaces` and updated `pve.local` in `/etc/hosts` to the LAN address, after restarting the proxmox web UI was only accessible on my internal network (https://10.26.x.x:8006).

Example interfaces file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp1s0
iface enp1s0 inet manual
#WAN

iface enp2s0 inet manual
#WAN failover

auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet manual
#LAN

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet manual
    bridge-ports enp1s0
    bridge-stp off
    bridge-fd 0
#WAN bridge

auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet static
    address 10.26.0.10/24
    gateway 10.26.0.1
    bridge-ports enp3s0
    bridge-stp off
    bridge-fd 0
#LAN bridge
```

Example hosts

```
127.0.0.1  localhost.localdomain localhost
10.26.0.10 pve.local pve
```

I left the proxmox Firewall enabled on `vmbr0` and disabled it on `vmbr1`. Proxmox's web UI should now be available at: https://10.26.0.10:8006